# Reading from a CSV file that has been imported into an SQL table as HEX data

Tags: sql, csv

I have a table in sql that is storing objects I am importing from the front end in what looks like HEX format (forgive me if I am wrong).

Here is an example "0xFFFE2200560065006E0064006F00720022" (this was thousands of lines long I only included the first line)

These are CSV files and I need to pull each row of the file and import it into another table as records.

Example of CSV:

TestItem1, 200

TestItem2, 200

TestItem3, 300

I have no control over the way that the file is uploaded/saved for security reasons so I will have to work with the hex data that is already in the table. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is not clear what is the problem and what you are facing with

Comment: Hi Adirmola, I am just not sure how to work with a file once it is in hex format in an SQL table.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I was looking for just going to post it here in case anyone else has trouble finding this:

```
Declare @data DocumentObjectType
Select top 1 @data = DocumentObject from DocumentObject 

SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), @data,2) AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
```